# Отображение одного <div>

Tags: php, javascript, html

В общем, у меня в БД есть записи, которые я вывожу на страницу в блоки "div".

```
<div class="container panel panel-primary">

        <?php foreach ($Questions as $Quest) { ?>

            <div id="<?=$Quest['id_rec']?>">
                <div class="name_question" align="center">
                    <h3><b><i> <?= $Quest->name_quest; ?> </i></b></h3>
                </div> <!-- <div class="name_question"> -->

                <div class="text_question">
                    <?= $Quest->text_quest; ?>
                </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

                <div class="answer">
                    <?php foreach ($Quest->squizqa as $Answer) { ?>
                        <p>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="<?=$Answer['id_rec']?>"> <?= $Answer->text_answer ?>
                        </p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->
            </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

У меня возник следующий вопрос. Как мне сделать так, что бы сначала показывался первый блок, при нажатии на клавишу "Следующий" или "Предыдущий", отображался следующий блок или предыдущий соответственно? Понимаю что надо подключать js и там прятать блоки и выводить их по порядку, но не могу найти конкретного примера с подобной реализацией, что бы посмотреть как это работает и как это реализовывать. Прошу вашей помощи, буду очень благодарен.

Сделал что у каждого "div" есть свой уникальный id адрес id="$Quest['id_rec']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и просили, вот пример:

```js
$(function() {
 var items = '.panel__item',
        $items = $(items),
        $btnPrev = $('.show-prev'),
        $btnNext = $('.show-next');
      
  $btnPrev.on('click', function() {
    showBlock('prev');
  })
  
  $btnNext.on('click', function() {
   showBlock('next');
  })
  
  function showBlock(current) {
   var $active = $(items + '.active'),
        index = $active.index();
        
    if(current == 'prev') {
     if(index == 0) {
      index = $items.length - 1;
     } else {
       index--;
      }
    } else {
      if(index == $items.length - 1) {
       index = 0;
      } else {
        index++;
      }
    }    
      
    $items.removeClass('active');
    $items.eq(index).addClass('active')
  }
  
})
```

```css
.panel__item {
  display: none;
}
.panel__item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel__item active" id="1">block1</div>
     <div class="panel__item" id="2">block2</div>
     <div class="panel__item" id="3">block3</div>
     <div class="panel__item" id="4">block4</div>
     <div class="panel__item" id="5">block5</div>
</div>

<a class="btn show-prev">Показать пред.</a>
<a class="btn show-next">Показать след.</a>
```

Сделал так, чтобы была бесконечная/круговая прокрутка, если этого не надо, в условиях можете поиграться.

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо)

Comment: Такой вопрос) Почему если указываться такую ссылку, то работает
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

А если указать вот так, то не работает
<script type="text/javascript" src="/common/assets/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: тут смотря как запускаешь htmlку. Попробуй убрать первый `/`, т.е.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="common/assets/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: к сожалению не помогло) эх, не могу понять почему не хочет работать так)

Answer (score 0):

Просто создаешь класс в котором прописываешь свойства, которые прячут дивку (visibility: false и/или display: none;), а в самом диве прописываешь обратное (т.е. true и block, соответственно). Потом с помощью jquery на нажатие следующий изменяешь классы дивов (ссылки внизу, если что) соответственно тому, какой ты хочешь показать(можно, кстати, ещё и z-index приписать в класс), а какие скрыть.

Смотри в этом направлении:

[.toggleClass() - изменение класса элемента](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

[.addClass( ) - добавление класса](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

[.removeClass( ) - удаление класса](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: А конкретный рабочий пример показать можете?